# Arithmetic Asian Option Pricing

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting the invalid procedure call or argument error on the definition of sigma2d line. 
Any idea how to avoid this code error?

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Application.Range("E19").value = ""

Application.Range("F19").value = ""
S0 = Application.Range("C5").value 'arithmetic average of underlying 1
K = Application.Range("C6").value 'strike
T = Application.Range("C10").value 'maturity
sigma = Application.Range("C8").value 'volatility
r = Application.Range("C8").value 'risk free rate
nsteps = Application.Range("C12").value 'no of timesteps
nsimulations = Application.Range("C13").value ' no of mc simulations
div = Application.Range("C9").value          'dividends
Randomize

Dim M1 As Double, M2 As Double, sigma2d As Double
Dim d1 As Double, d2 As Double, Nd1 As Double, Nd2 As Double

M1 = (Exp((r - div) * T) - 1) / (r - div) * T

v = (2 * Exp((2 * r) - (2 * div) + (sigma * sigma) * T)) * S0 * S0
w = (r - div + (sigma * sigma)) * (2 * r - 2 * q + (sigma * sigma)) * T * T
Z = 2 * S0 * S0 / ((r - div) * T * T)

y = (1 / 2 * (r - div) + sigma * sigma)
h = Exp((r - div) * T) / (r - div + (sigma * sigma))

M2 = (v / w) + Z * (y - h)
M3 = M1 * M1

sigma2d = Log(M2 / M3)
d1 = (Log(M1 / K) + (sigma2d * T) / 2) / sigma * Sqr(T)
d2 = d1 - sigma * Sqr(T)

callArith = Exp(-r * T) * (M1 * Nd1 - K * Nd2)
Application.Range("E19").value = Application.Max(ExactCall, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to do the log of a negative number?  Set a breakpoint and check variables before that line.  Maybe you have an error before that generating a negative.

Comment: That's probably the answer.

Comment: Let me know if you get it working and can accept my answer or not!

Answer (score 0):

First check the argument to the `Log` function is positive.

Failing that, it could be due to a missing reference in the project. This manifests itself in this curious way. Have a look at "Tools", "References" and see if there is one missing.

You can write `sigma2d = Vba.Log(M2 / M3)` instead but that's only really a short fix since missing references will cause you headaches elsewhere.

One more thing, why not create a *function* instead, passing in all the variables as function parameters? Your spreadsheet will be more stable if you do that.

(Also, at the end of your code, `d1` definition is incorrect. You need brackets around `sigma * Sqr(T)`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a pair of `()` or do `"/T"` as you are multiplying by `T` here:

```
M1 = (Exp((r - div) * T) - 1) / (r - div) * T
```